# Case (or alternative) statement to select which query criteria to use

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to use a conditional statement to determine which set of query criteria to use.  Open to any suggestions.  Currently I have

```
Select p.1, p.2, p.3, Count(p.3) ASDF
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.a = t1.a
inner join table3 t3 on t3.b = t1.b
where
    case t1.abc
        when 'x' then
            t2 in ('1111','2222')
    else t3.123 in ('asdf','qwer')

and t2.ad = '123'
and t1.bn = '456'
and t3.mk = '678'
group by p.1, p.2, p.3
```

I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near" the first 'in' and the following 'else'.  Is what I am asking possible?  If not, what is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you want:

```
SELECT p.1, p.2, p.3, COUNT(p.3) ASDF
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.a = t1.a
INNER JOIN table3 t3 
    ON t3.b = t1.b
WHERE ((t1.abc = 'x' AND t2.somecolumn IN ('1111','2222'))
        OR t1.abc <> 'x' AND t3.123 in ('asdf','qwer'))
AND t2.ad = '123'
AND t1.bn = '456'
AND t3.mk = '678'
GROUP BY p.1, p.2, p.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.1, p.2, p.3, Count(p.3) ASDF
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.a = t1.a
inner join table3 t3 on t3.b = t1.b
where (t1.abc = 'x'AND t2 in ('1111','2222')) OR
      (t1.abc <> 'x' AND t3.123 in ('asdf','qwer'))

and t2.ad = '123'
and t1.bn = '456'
and t3.mk = '678'
group by p.1, p.2, p.3
```